# Why Actionresult Method is not called from javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I have to write this statement into Javascript for call Controller Actionresult Method with ID

```
 function submitForm(state)
 {


     if (state != "") 
     {

         alert("Hellooo");

         var ele = document.getElementById('gridform').elements;

        var strvalue = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) 
        {

            if (ele[i].type == "checkbox") 
            {

                if (ele[i].name == "chkactive[]")
                 {

                     if (ele[i].checked == true)
                     {

                        if (strvalue != "")
                            strvalue = strvalue + "," + ele[i].value;
                        else
                            strvalue = ele[i].value;

                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    alert("ok fine" + strvalue);

    if (strvalue != null) 
    {
        alert("NOT Null");
    }


    $.post('@Url.Action("Useractive","Admin", new{})' + '?Id=' + strvalue);
```

but I can't call the UserActive method of Admin controller 
I can't get any error for calling this statement but just not navigate with id in to method of controller...
please help me what is the reason what I do wrong..!

this is my Controller Action method:-

```
public ActionResult Useractive(string Id)
    {

        int[] numbers = Id.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();

        foreach (int id in numbers)
        {
            User_Master u_master = db.User_Masters.Find(id);
            if (u_master.Is_active == "False")
            {
                u_master.Is_active = "True";
                db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Userlist","Admin");

    }
```

Comment: Do you see any messages in the console for the dev tools on whatever browser you are using?  I trimmed down your javascript and posted a hard-coded strvalue to a stripped down admin controller implementing your methods (skipped the database stuff, returned a string in Userlist) and everything seemed to work ok.

Comment: sir....above i have posted my statement are work well in my normal project but this is not work in when i have to host my project on IIS and run this at that time operation are not perform and Action result methis of controller are not call ... but normally can perform so please help me..! @Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your .post method:

```
$.post("@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.UserActive())", { Id: strvalue) }, function(data) {
    //Do Something.
});
```

Comment: $.post('@Url.Action("Useractive","Admin", new{})' + '?Id=' + strvalue);   ...... this statement is work in my normal project and call the action method of controller but this statement are not work and action method of controller are not call when i have host my project on IIS and while this is not not work so,, what's reason behind that..please help me..!